# Why is my permutation algorithm giving me the same result for all permutations?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, permutation, heaps-algorithm

I'm stuck with some heap's permutation algorithm. I wrote some JavaScript code to recursively find every possible permutation of a value: either an array or a string. My code seems to work perfectly when I `console.log()` the permuted values but when I push them to another array I get the same value for all of them. I'm confused.

My code contains two separate functions: one does the swapping of the elements and the other one recursively finds the possible permutation:

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
newArr = [];

// swap mechanism here
function swap(arr, pos1, pos2) {
    var temp = arr[pos1];
    arr[pos1] = arr[pos2];
    arr[pos2] = temp;
};

function perm(arr, nArr, n) {
    n = n || arr.length; 
    if (n === 1) {
        console.log(arr); // console.log() works great
        newArr.push(arr); // pushing the permuted values does not
    }
    else {
        for(var i = 1; i <= n; i += 1) {
            perm(arr, nArr, n - 1);
            if (n % 2) {
                var j = 1;
            }
            else {
                var j = i;
            }
            swap(arr, j - 1, n - 1);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple (heap) reference vs. (stack) value question. The reason is quite simple: `arr` in all recursive calls references the same array in memory.  Thus when you call `newArr.push(arr)` another reference to the same object is added to the result list. And when you do `swap`, you swap elements for all elements of `newArr` as they point to the same array. See also [Copying array by value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript) for a possible workaround. (Basically use [`Array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method to create an independent copy).

Comment: Thank you so much, brother. I was so confused but I think I'm understanding what the issue was. One quick question: How come console.log() would show all the permuted values? I don't quite understand that part.

Comment: @WadsonFourrien, `console.log` show current value at the moment of execution. At that moment the (only) array is in the state you want (and all references from `newArr` point to the same array in that state). But when you call `swap` next time you modify that (the same) array and its state is now different from the one that you've logged last time. It might be helpful to set a breakpoint and look at the `newArr` on 3rd or 4th iteration to see how it contains several references to the same memory.